# GET different url based on inputbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using the asp.net MVC pattern of having a url like `controller/action/id`. This works fine if I navigate to the url directly.

I want to have a page where the user can input the `id` and click a button (or link) which takes them to the correct url.

Do I need to somehow make an action link that points to a varying url based on the input using some client-side script?
Or can I render a Form that `GET`s the correct url?

Is what I'm doing unusual; should I be doing something else? (Note that the number of ids is too long to list).

Comment: It's probably easier to do this clientside with some JavaScript than in your code-behind.

Comment: The simplest way to do it involves POSTing a form and then redirecting based on input. Other than that - Javascript (or jQuery, if you like the framework) to minimize the traffic (redirections and posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the default route set up, you can do the following client-side script (make sure it's in the same file though):

```
var yourLink = '@Url.Action("controller", "action")';
//should output controller/action/
```

Then assuming your button has the id `myButton` and the textbox has the id `myTextBox`, you can do this jQuery:

```
$("#myButton").click(function () {
    location.href = yourLink + $("#myTextBox").val();
    //should output controller/action/5 for example, although you might
    //want to make sure they've put a "correct" value in here
});
```